# Any way to load/execute scripts (game-logic) included in a post-release DLC (Unity3D AssetBundles) on iOS since it seems its not allowed?

Tags: unity, ios, client-server

We are making a game where players will be granted access to new levels every week and these new levels will probably be downloaded from our server as [Unity Asset Bundles](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html)
The only issue is, as mentioned [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/scriptsinassetbundles.html) , ios and other app stores dont allow loading/executing of scripts this way even if they allow you to load these newer asset bundles without doing the full update cycle. So really we need to know how game-logic scripts, etc can be executed for the new levels that are going to be released via Asset Bundles and downloaded from our server. Our server will be authoritative btw. I am sure there is a way since big game publishers are able to do post-release DLC and really, thats what we are after too - Just more regularly, whilst being in-line with app store regulations. 
Our usual workflow until now was just publish and then release a big update months down the line. Not every week.

Comment: From what I've seen all your script code gets built into a DLL on build. Replace this DLL with an updated version and your asset bundles should be able to access these new scripts. I've tested this ( replacing the DLL in a build ) and it did work. However, I'm not sure if this will work in every situation.

Comment: I wanted to comment in the other question but I can't. You say "big game publishers are able to do post-release DLC" but are you sure they are loading scripts? It's really a need in your game to load new scripts with new levels? Again, I'm answering as android developer.

Answer (score 2):

Many games are data driven, and apple is fine with you downloading data from your servers which changes the behavior of the game, adds content, etc.  If you can't do with data what you need to do, you have to put out a new exe that exposes new features to data, that will let you do more without executable patching. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not that uncommon to release new "downloadable" content with a mandatory patch which is rolled out to all users through the normal app updating system and then just unlock it when the user paid for it.